# Height of div container defined with 100vh is too big (look as it orientates itself on window size)

Tags: html, css

I define a grid in css as follows:

```css
.main {
    display: grid;
    /*
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Header                                                      ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Structures ¦ Main (ortho-viewer)                            ¦
    ¦            ¦                                                ¦
    ¦            ¦                                                ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Footer                                                      ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
     */
    grid-template-columns: 25vw 75vw ;
    grid-template-rows: 8vh 84vh 8vh;
}
.header {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}
.ortho-viewer {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.structures{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.structures h3 {
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I also defined the box model to make sure I do not face a problem with padding and margins:

```css
html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
 }
```

But the resulting layout exceeds the viewport height and scrollbar is shown. What do I need to do to get the expected grid configuration?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is `body {margin: 0;}`
What causes this overlapping is: `.main {grid-template-rows: 8vh 84vh 8vh;}`
So you can [play with that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) to get desired results.

Example with `auto`:

```css
html {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 0;} /* added */
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  outline: 1px solid red; /* just for demo */
 }

.main {

    /*
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Header                                                      ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Structures ¦ Main (ortho-viewer)                            ¦
    ¦            ¦                                                ¦
    ¦            ¦                                                ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
    ¦ Footer                                                      ¦
    ¦-------------------------------------------------------------¦
     */
    grid-template-columns: 25vw 75vw ;
    grid-template-rows: 8vh auto 8vh; /* changed from 84vh */
    display: grid;

}
.header {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}
.ortho-viewer {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.structures{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.structures h3 {
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="main">main
  <div class="ortho-viewer">Viewer</div>
</div>
<div class="structures"><h3>Title</h3></div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately this did not resolve my problem. I have body margin 0, and also played with the row definitions - still the same.

Comment: Well it seems @Paulie_D suggestion to use different measurement fix that (:

Answer (score 0):

Just clean default margin of the body.

```
body {
    margin: 0
}
```

[See on Codepen](https://codepen.io/rinbui2207/pen/yLBROqR?editors=1100#anon-signup)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately this did not resolve my problem. Strangely I also see the same behavior on your codepen example ...

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the difference bewtween `vh` and `fr` being interpreted by the browser when combined with the `padding` you have applied to some of these elements.

If you substitute `fr` for your row/column valies the overflow dissappears.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  /* grid-template-rows: 8vh 84vh 8vh; */
  grid-template-rows: 8fr 84fr 8fr;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.ortho-viewer {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.structures {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.structures h3 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="structures"></div>
  <div class="ortho-viewer"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```